# Unable to force left align text in rmarkdown document

Tags: r-markdown

I'm using R markdown for a university assignment. I'd like to have questions number/letters left aligned on my document, but rmarkdown is adding spaces before "a)" and "b)", which I'd like to be aligned with the rest of my text.

```
 ---
title: "Untitled"
author: "dsn084"
date: "26 March 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

This is a paragraph.

a) this is part a.

b) this is part b.
```

And my output ... 
[image: RMarkdown Output]

Comment: Might try putting something like `a\)` so it doesn't treat this as a list.

Comment: Perfect, Matt, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using output: pdf_document, the rmarkdown document will be converted into latex before pdf, so you can use latex instructions to accomplish that.

`flushleft` will do it. Example:

> This is a paragraph.
>
> \begin{flushleft}
>
> a) this is part a.
>
> b) this is part b.
>
> \end{flushleft}